# How to get notified of a status change when each class has its own status type?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have classes that each class has its own status type. The consumer, which is aware of all object types, must be notified of the change in the state of each object and act accordingly. The solution I came up with is to create an interface with an event that each class will have to implement and the consumer will do the casting based on the process type passed as an argument to the event.

It seems to work and I know people will say that's all that matters, but it feels as not a very good solution since every time I add a new process I have to add quite a lot of code, like implementing a new `ProcessEventArgsX` by adding a new condition to `HandleStatus` method, etc.

Is there desing patter that I'm missing or is there a better solution?

```
class ProcessA : IProcess 
{
   enum StatusA { ... }
   class ProcessEventArgsA : EventArgs { public StatusA Status { get; set; } }
}

class ProcessB : IProcess 
{
   enum StatusB { ... }
   class ProcessEventArgsB : EventArgs { public StatusB Status { get; set; } }
}

class ProcessX : IProcess { ... }

interface IProcess 
{
   event Action<ProcessType, EventArgs> StatusChanged;
}

// Consumer

List<IProcess> _processes;
void Subscribe()
{
   foreach(var proc in _processes)
   {
       proc.StatusChanged += HandleStatus;
   }
}

void HandleStatus(ProcessType processType, EventArgs e)
{
   if(processType == ProcessType.A)
   {
       var args = e as ProcessEventArgsA;
       StatusA status = args.Status;
    
       DoSomethingBasedOnStatusFromProcessA(status);
   } 
   else if(processType == ProcessType.A) {}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Since each class has its own status type, if you don't like using one handler to handle various status types, you can only use a particular handler to handle a particular status type, unless you have a uniform process (except the status type) to handle them.

Comment: @shingo, do you mean the consumer will have map of handlers per status type? Meaning `HandleStatus` will do somthing like `_handlers[processType].Handle()`?

Comment: Yes, something like this, perhaps different statuses can be filtered out during subscription.